The mongo express container is not properly communicating with the mongoDB container. How can i fix this?
When I run docker-compose -f mongo-services.yaml up to compose this file below:
services: 

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: supersecret

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports: 
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: supersecret
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo
    depends_on:
      - "mongodb"

I tried to compose this file. I expected the mongo-express to connect the mongodb which it did for a split 30's then it continually disconnects as it shows.
 Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://admin:****@mongo:27017/"

mongo-express-1  | /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:285

mongo-express-1  |                 const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);

mongodb-1        | {"t":{"$date":"2024-09-10T16:35:53.056+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTCHKPT",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1725986153,"ts_usec":56936,"thread":"1:0x7ff8cf000640","session_name":"WT_SESSION.checkpoint","category":"WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS","category_id":6,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"saving checkpoint snapshot min: 4, snapshot max: 4 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 7"}}}


The mongodb service (thus, host name for the compose) is called mongodb, not mongo, so change this:
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo
to:
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongodb

Should be mongod, not mongodb (unless something recently changed?)

@DavidMakogon why so? the service in the compose file is called mongodb. This is not the daemon executable name... it's the host where the database is, and on compose by default, that's the name of the service (mongodb: in the compose yaml file)

The express service is trying to connect (look at his logs) to a hostname called mongo (the end of the connection string: mongodb://admin:****@mongo:27017/). It doesn't exist, so it's timing out... but mongodb does exist on that compose

Ah - right. Was thinking of the service/daemon name.
